# Technique for drawing theme element (i.e. how to not stretch draw)?

Tags: windows, algorithm, themes

I'm looking at drawing a custom theme element onto a device content.

For example's sake, i will use the [HeaderItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.header.item?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) from the Windows XP header/listview:

[image] *(18×18 px)*

Which we can blow up to see a little easier:

[image]

> **Note**: I am not using the [Theme API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground), nor am i asking about using the Theme API.

If i have my bitmap, like the one above, how can i draw it in practice?

### Stretch draw ruins the style

The important problem that needs solving is how to maintain the important details. You can see the actual Windows XP Header draws the right-edge vertical line nice and crisp:

[image]

But if i were to blindly [**StretchBlt**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) the image, the details become fuzzy:

[image]

The issue also happens with theme elements with crisp horizontal feature when the image is stretched vertically. In this case it also messes up the vertical gradient. But some other element have it even more pronounced.

So what is the technique that can be used to address this?

Should i cut `6 px` off the top, left, bottom, and right?:

[image]

And then rather than drawing 1 image, i draw nine?:

[image]

And draw them with various horizontal or vertical stretch rules depending where it is?:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] Unstretched | [image] Horizontally stretched | Unstretched [image] |
| [image]Vertically stretched | [image] Horizontally and vertically stretched | Vertically stretched [image] |
| [image]Unstretched | Horizontally stretched [image] | Unstretched [image] |

This must be a solved problem already; since Windows already solved it, and who knows how many more Widget libraries that support themes.

Comment: If you are not using the Theme API, where did the bitmap come from? The classic/non-Theme API does not use bitmaps at all.

Comment: *"Where did the bitmap come from?"* Photoshop.

Comment: (And i've reached my limit trying to reproduce designer's designs using [**MoveToEx**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-movetoex), [**LineTo**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-lineto), [**GradientFill**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gradientfill), etc, and it's time to figure out how Windows, Delphi, and every other application that has styles does, it and just **draw** the image i'm given by the designer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's solution to this problem can be reverse engineered by looking at the **NormalBlue.ini** file inside **Luna.msstyles**. Looking at the entry for [**Header.HeaderItem**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.header.item?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

**NormalBlue.ini**:

```
[Header.HeaderItem]
bgtype = imagefile
SizingMargins = 8, 8, 3, 4
ContentMargins = 3, 0, 0, 0
ImageFile = Blue\ListViewHeader.bmp
imageCount=5
imageLayout=vertical
sizingType = tile
transparent=true
transparentcolor=255 0 0
FillColorHint = 250 248 243; Average fill color (light beige)
AccentColorHint = 252 194 71; Rollover hilite color (orange)
```

First we see it references the **\Blue\ListViewHeader.bmp**:

```
ImageFile = Blue\ListViewHeader.bmp
```

Which is:

[image]

And then there's the magic piece:

```
SizingMargins = 8, 8, 3, 4
```

This corresponds to [`TMT_SIZINGMARGINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/property-typedefs):

> `TMT_SIZINGMARGINS`: The margins used for sizing a non-true-size image.

where you can see some more hints in **TmSchema.h**:

```
//---- rendering MARGIN properties ----
TM_PROP(3601, TMT, SIZINGMARGINS,     MARGINS)    // margins used for 9-grid sizing
```

*"Margins used for 9-grid sizing"*. This is a reference to the idea that you split up the image into 3x3 grid, and size the chunks independently as appropriate.

And the final piece is the documentation of the `MARGINS` type in **UxTheme.h**:

```
typedef struct _MARGINS
{
    int cxLeftWidth;      // width of left border that retains its size
    int cxRightWidth;     // width of right border that retains its size
    int cyTopHeight;      // height of top border that retains its size
    int cyBottomHeight;   // height of bottom border that retains its size
} MARGINS, *PMARGINS;
```

and its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/ns-uxtheme-margins):

- **cxLeftWidth**: int - Width of the left border that retains its size.
- **cxRightWidth**: int - Width of the right border that retains its size.
- **cyTopHeight**: int - Height of the top border that retains its size.
- **cyBottomHeight**: int - Height of the bottom border that retains its size.

## Chop and Paint

The Luna theme is telling us that when we draw **ListViewHeader.bmp**, we need to use the sizing margins:

```
SizingMargins = 8, 8, 3, 4
```

And cut the image up into 9 pieces (3x3). But rather than using 6px all around (like i said in my question), we need to use the sizes that the designer of the image intended:

- **Left:** 8
- **Right:** 8
- **Top:** 3
- **Bottom:** 4

So given the 18×18 theme element image created in Photoshop by a designer:

[image]

The person who created the image said that my drawing code needs to cut off:

- left 8 pixels
- right 8 pixels
- top 3 pixels
- bottom 4 pixels

[image]

Meaning i then have to draw each of the nine images:

[image]

And then stretch draw some parts in certain directions:

[image]

- Top-left: draw unstretched
- Left: stretch vertically
- Bottom-left: draw unstretched
- Top: draw stretch horizontally
- Middle: draw stretched horizontally and vertically
- Bottom: draw stretched horizontally
- Top-right: draw unstretched
- Right: draw stretched vertically
- Bottom-right: draw unstretched